# PhoneGap 3: Exclude folders from being copied to the platforms

Tags: cordova

I'm using PhoneGap 3.x and to develop the UI I'm using some npm tools like Grunt and Bower. These tools generate some folders with downloaded content (node_modules and bower_components) that, when copied to a platform folder, make my app heavier (~40MB more).

Is there any way to tell phonegap to exclude certain files/folders when building the app for any platform in specific or in general?

Answer (score 0):

Found no way to prevent the folder from being copied, added a script instead under `hooks/after_prepare/cleanup_platform.sh`:

```
rm -rf ./platforms/ios/www/node_modules
```

They just on the console:

```
chmod a+x hooks/after_prepare/cleanup_platform.sh
```

This will delete the undesired files from my platform slimming my app package.

Note that I'm posting this answer as a reference/temporal/straightforward solution that would work on UNIX workstations; per the hooks README, this script has to be rewritten in node in order to be cross-platform: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

Comment: Man this is exactly what I've been looking for for quite some time ... any chance you could provide a version that works in OSX terminal? Is that chmod bit some kind of permissions thing? Also will this delete non-empty folders too?

Comment: I'm still using this workaround in a OS X computer and yes, it will delete non-empty folders too